# d3js toggling bars animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to animate the bars when the user clicks on the legend. I've built the update function - but I am unsure on how to do the required filter and animation for this feature

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/211/

```
  function update(){
  console.log("data", data);

  var barData = data.filter(function(d1) { 
    console.log("d1", d1);

    return !d1.disabled; 
  });
  console.log("barData", barData);

  var bar = chartHolder.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
   console.log("bar", bar);


   bar.transition()
   .attr("width", x0.rangeBand())
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return 0;
        //return y(d.value); 
       })
      .attr("height", function(d) { 
        return 0;
        //return height - y(d.value); 
       });

  bar.exit().remove();

/*
  var bar = bar.selectAll("rect")

   bar.transition()
      //.attr("id", function(d){ return 'tag'+d.state.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '');})
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("width", x0.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return 0;
        //return y(d.value); 
       })
      .attr("height", function(d) { 
        return 0;
        //return height - y(d.value); 
       });

    //bar.exit().remove();
  */
```

Answer (score 0):

This code `var bar = chartHolder.selectAll(".bar")` returns empty selection. You should select all `.bars` apply new data with method `data`, after that select all `react`, set animation parameters `transition`, `duration`, `delay` and set new values for approptiate attributes.

I rewrite your code - http://jsfiddle.net/168x28p3/1/ Here, I simply animate height of bars after click on legend. But this way you can create the another animation which you need.

```js
var $this = document.querySelector('.chart');

var data = [{
  label: "a",
  "Current Period": 20,
  "Prior Year": 10
}, {
  label: "b",
  "Current Period": 15,
  "Prior Year": 30
}, {
  label: "c",
  "Current Period": 25,
  "Prior Year": 40
}, {
  label: "d",
  "Current Period": 5,
  "Prior Year": 60
}];

var configuration = [{
  "yLabel": "People Count"
}];


var w = 660;
var h = 500;

function colores_google(n) {
  var colores_g = ["#f7b363", "#448875", "#c12f39", "#2b2d39", "#f8dd2f", "#8bf41b"];
  return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
}


var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 110,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  },
  width = w - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;



var svg = d3.select($this).append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var axisHolder = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis");
var chartHolder = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "chart");
var legendHolder = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend");

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

//var colorRange = d3.scale.category20();
//var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
//.range(colorRange.range());

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var divTooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");


var options = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "label";
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.valores = options.map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      value: +d[name]
    };
  });
});

x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.label;
}));
x1.domain(options).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d.valores, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
})]);

axisHolder.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

axisHolder.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(configuration[0].yLabel);

var bar = chartHolder.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bars")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.label) + ",0)";
  });

bar.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.valores;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.name);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colores_google(i);
  });

bar
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    divTooltip.style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px");
    divTooltip.style("top", d3.event.pageY - 25 + "px");
    divTooltip.style("display", "inline-block");
    var x = d3.event.pageX,
      y = d3.event.pageY
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
    l = elements.length
    l = l - 1
    elementData = elements[l].__data__
    divTooltip.html((d.label) + "<br>" + elementData.name + "<br>" + elementData.value + "%");
  });
bar
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    divTooltip.style("display", "none");
  });


var legend = legendHolder.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(options.slice())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + margin.right + "," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colores_google(i);
  })
  .on("click", function(d) {
    console.log("d", d);
    d.disabled = !d.disabled;
    update();
  });

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });




function update() {
  var barData = data.map(item => {
    item.valores = item.valores.map(valor => {
      return Object.assign({}, valor, { value: Math.random() * 40 })
    })
    return item;
  })

  var bar = chartHolder.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(barData)

  var rect = bar.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.valores;
    })

  rect
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .delay(100)
    .attr("width", x0.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
       return height - y(d.value);
    });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffd;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.toolTip {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 15px #888888;
  color: black;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.legend {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 60%;
}

rect {
  stroke-width: 2;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis .tick line {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.axisHorizontal path {
  fill: none;
}

.axisHorizontal line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axisHorizontal .tick line {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
  fill-opacity: .9;
}


/*
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

Comment: I see - so if you fed barData - instead of data - that would start to prune the bars?

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer. Look at `update` function. I generate new random data with `Math.random` after click on legend and update bars with animation. Use this way: 1 - Create new data, which you need for your case. 2 - Apply new data on appropriate elements with `.data` method.

Comment: I tried to add this disable flag - but it doesn't hold in the filtering?    d.disabled = !d.disabled;